# Cannot use bindNodeCallback with node-mysql connection.query

Tags: node.js, rxjs, node-mysql, node-mysql2

I'm trying to use [bindNodeCallback](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/bindNodeCallback) to convert `connection.query` into a function that returns observable.

```js
const mysql = require('mysql2');
const { bindNodeCallback } = require("rxjs");
const connection = mysql.createConnection({host:"servername", user: "u", password:"p", database:"mydb" });

connection.connect();
let q = 'SELECT 1 from dual';
//1.This works. Default api
connection.query(q, (err, v)=>console.log(v));

//2.this throws: TypeError: Cannot read property 'config' of undefined
//bindNodeCallback(connection.query)(q).subscribe(v=>console.log(v));

//3.This returns a two dimensional array where the first element contains an array with the results and the second an array of ColumnDefinition.
bindNodeCallback(connection.query).call(connection, q).subscribe(v=>console.log(v));
```

**Statement 1 prints:** `[ TextRow { '1': 1 } ]`

**Statement 2 throws:** `TypeError: Cannot read property 'config' of undefined`  and after debugging the code I saw that it references `this.config` (inside Connection object) which according to [the doc](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/bindNodeCallback) needs to be provided when calling the output function.

So I add `this` to statement 3 but for some reason I don't get what I expect:

**Statement 3 prints:** `[[ TextRow { '1': 1 } ],[ColumnDefinition { _buf:..., _clientEncoding: 'utf-8'....]]`

**My question** is, how should I use `bindNodeCallback()` to print the results that statement 1 prints?

Note: In case you want to test this issue with an older version of `mysql` you can use `mysql` instead of `mysql2` where the same issue occurs just with differrent types `TextRow`=>`RowDataPacket` and `ColumnDefinition`=>`FieldPacket`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bindNodeCallback` will create a function that returns an observable to which subscribing will stream one and only value containing:

- the param passed to callback (if one)
- `array` of params passed to callback (if more than one).

`mysql` and `mysql2` pass two parameters to the callback of `query()`: one is an array containing the results and the other is an array containing the column definitions.

To verify call `connection.query(q, (err, v, colDef)=>console.log(v, colDef));` to see that it will also print the column definitions.

So since the parameters are two, the function passed to subscribe should receive an array, not a single param.

"how should I use `bindNodeCallback()` to print the results that statement 1 prints?"

Call it as you do now, just pass from `map` for getting only the first param (param at index 0 of the callback params array):

```js
bindNodeCallback(connection.query).call(connection,q)
.pipe(map(arr=>arr[0])).subscribe(v=>console.log(v));
```